# Autocomplete doesn't always work in Radcombobox

Tags: wpf, telerik, radcombobox

I've noticed that the first time I click in a radcombobox, the autocomplete doesn't work.  It doesn't matter if there is previous data in the combobox or the combobox is blank, the autocomplete does not work.

To get it to work, I have to either select something first, or reselect the previous entry.

Is there a way around this?  Thanks

XAML:

```
                        <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboUpperDoorStyle" 
                                         FontSize="16" Margin="0,8,0,0" Background="#F6F8FA" BorderBrush="#D7D8DD" 
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding}" Text="{Binding upperDoorStyle, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                         TextSearch.TextPath="DoorStyle" IsEditable="True" Style="{DynamicResource RadComboBoxStyle3}" >
                        <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding DoorStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Binding:

```
        Dim da As New SqlCeDataAdapter(s, myConn.xxx)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        thisCombo.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView

        thisCombo.IsTextSearchEnabled = True
        thisCombo.StaysOpenOnEdit = True
```

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help you if you don't post any code?  Are you following the demo here?  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: See edits.  Coding is not that out of the ordinary.  I used telerik's WPF examples as a guide.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the WPF tag and thought you were working in WebForms.  Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough to help you there :(

Comment: I think the item template is the problem.  If I remove that, then autocomplete works as expected.  Is there a way to have both?  Thanks.